# How to find out unlock method programmatically?

Tags: java, android, keyguard, keyguardlock

For the Android OS, I need to find out what the user uses to unlock the device. Be it null, PIN, pattern, fingerprint.

Comment: Erm ...... why?

Comment: Because the boss said so.

Comment: Why did the boss say so?   'Cos this sounds like the kind of thing that could have (bad) security implications for the user.

Comment: Well yes ... but the considerations part may inform you if it is likely to be possible to do this.  The functionality may not be supported *because of* the security and privacy considerations.  At that point, knowing what you are actually trying to achieve might allow someone to suggest **better** alternatives to you / your boss.

Answer (score 4):

To Detect if an authenticated fingerprint exists:

```
FingerprintManagerCompat fingerprintManagerCompat = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context);

if (fingerprintManagerCompat.isHardwareDetected() && fingerprintManagerCompat.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) { 
    // Device supports fingerprint authentication and has registered a fingerprint     
}
```

To use this you also need to add a permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

To check if lock pattern is enabled:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

int lockPatternEnable = Settings.Secure.getInt(cr, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED, 0);
// If user has pattern unlock then lockPatternEnable will be 1 else 0
```

There is no explicit way to check for pin/password as far as I'm aware but 
you can use KeyGuardManager's [isDeviceSecure()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isDeviceSecure()) method

which returns `true` if device is secured with a PIN, pattern or password.
Coupled with the pattern check you can detect if pin is enabled.

Remember to test for fingerprint first because it requires a pin/password unlock to be set as well